# RDBMS Modeling: Many to Many with Extreme Historical Versioning

Tags: mysql, oracle, postgresql, database-design, rdbms

You have two tables, `foo` and `bar`, that have a `M:N` relationship.

You want to maintain pretty extreme historical versions of both `foo` and `bar`, and also the relationship between them, such that:

1. You insert a row into `Foo`, and then insert a row into `Bar`, and then insert a row into `FooBar` linking the two together. You should be able to look back in time and see that the row in `Foo` was once independent, as was the row in `Bar`.
2. You then insert another row into `Bar`, and insert a row into `FooBar` linking this second `bar` to the first `foo`. You should be able to look back in time and see that the `foo` row was linked to only the first `bar` row.
3. You then update one of the attributes of the `foo` row. You should be able to look back in time and see that both of the rows in `Bar` were once linked to the `foo` row that had the previous attribute.

**While I was able to implement this, my solution is rather tedious and results in a large number of DML operations for a single update/insert. Adding a Baz table with a M:N between Bar and Baz would dramatically increase the number of DMLs. Is there a standard way to accomplish this task better than what follows?**

Here is my solution:

---

**DDL**

```
Foo
--------------
foo_id            INT            --sequence generated
foo_version_id    INT     UNIQUE --sequence generated
foo_name          VARCHAR
active            INT     CHECK (active in (0,1))
CONSTRAINT  PRIMARY_KEY (foo_id, foo_version_id)


Bar
--------------
bar_id            INT            --sequence generated
bar_version_id    INT     UNIQUE --sequence generated
bar_name          VARCHAR
active            INT     CHECK (active in (0,1))
CONSTRAINT  PRIMARY_KEY (bar_id, bar_version_id)

FooBar
--------------
foo_version_id    FK to foo.foo_version_id
bar_version_id    FK to bar.bar_version_id
CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (foo_version_id, bar_version_id)
```

**DML**

The following is the pseudo code for each of the three cases. I have implemented these as procedures.

For **case #1**, this results in 4 DML operations to link two independent `foo` and `bar`s together, not including the first two lines:

```
Insert the first foo row
Insert the first bar row
Update the first foo row and set active to 0. 
Insert a new foo row with the same foo_id, foo_name, but new foo_version_id
Update the first bar row and set active to 0
Insert a new bar row and with the same bar_id, bar_name, but new bar_version_id
Insert a row into foo_bar with the foo_version_id and bar_version_id from the newly created active foo and bar rows.
```

For **case #2**, this results in 9 DML operations to link a new `bar` to the `foo` that is linked to the first `bar`, not including the first line:

```
Insert the second bar row 
Update the active foo and set active to 0
Insert a new foo row with same foo_id, foo_name, but new foo_version_id
Update the first active bar and set active to 0
Insert a new bar row with same bar_id, bar_name, but new bar_version_id
Update the second active bar and set active to 0
Insert a new bar row with same bar_id, bar_name, but new bar_version_id
Insert a row into foo_bar with the foo_version_id and bar_version_id from the foo and first bar.
Insert a row into foo_bar with the foo_version_id and bar_version_id from the foo and second bar.
```

For **case #3**, this results in 8 DML operations to update an attribute on a `foo` that is linked to two `bars`:

```
Update the active foo and set active to 0
Insert a new foo row with same foo_id, but new foo_version_id, foo_name
(repeat from case #2 starting at line 4)
```

---

**SQL**

Given a known `foo_id`, I can left join `foo`, `foo_bar`, `bar` on `foo_version_id` and `bar_version_id` and see every possible historical state that the particular foo in question was.

```
select f.foo_id, f.foo_version_id, f.foo_name, b.bar_id, b.bar_version_id, b.bar_name
FROM foo f, foo_bar fb, bar b
WHERE 1 = 1
    AND f.foo_version_id = fb.foo_version_id (+)
    AND fb.bar_version_id = b.bar_version_id (+)
ORDER BY f.foo_version_id, b.bar_version_id
;

foo_id | foo_version_id | foo_name | bar_id | bar_version_id | bar_name
     1 |              1 |        a |        |                |           -- 1) independent foo
     1 |              2 |        a |      1 |              2 |       b   -- 2) link foo to first bar
     1 |              3 |        a |      1 |              4 |       b   -- 3) link second bar to foo
     1 |              3 |        a |      2 |              5 |       b2  -- 3) link second bar to foo
     1 |              4 |        A |      1 |              6 |       b   -- 4) rename foo_name to A
     1 |              4 |        A |      2 |              7 |       b2  -- 4) rename foo_name to A
```

Comment: Can you explain why you need this level of historical detail?

Comment: @RickJames I have a business requirement that states the user should be able to flash back to any configuration of `foo` and `bar` that the user had ever had in the past. In this case, a `foo` by definition includes all of the associated `bars`, and vice versa. Changing an attribute on the current `foo` then changes the nature of the associated `bars`, and vice versa.

Comment: Does the 'owner' of this requirement understand that the resulting database system will cost 10 times as much to build and maintain?

Comment: Might a "compromise" of "flash back to the one dump that was taken yesterday" suffice?

Comment: You're talking about a temporal database, which was added to the standard in [SQL-201111](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2011) (ISO/IEC 9075:201). As far as I know only [Oracle has implemented](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_flashback.htm#ADFNS1008) it (partially) so far. If you want to maintain the FK relationships then you're not going to get much better than this. If you don't mind not enforcing the FK relationships then it becomes a lot easier...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a Temporal Database, ie one that supports SQL:2011 Temporal (or a similar proprietary system)

No open source databases support this to my knowledge. I've been pestering the Posgres guys to do it for a while.

This means you need to shell out some cash. The following DBs support it:

IBM DB2 10+
Oracle 12c
MS SQL Server 2016